# Google Spreadsheet API Error Requested entity was not found

Tags: laravel, google-sheets-api

I'm setting up simple website based on Laravel 5.8 that use Google Spreadsheet as database.
I created OAuth 2.0 Client ID, Service Account, API Key and set settings.
I also shared my spreadsheet with created OAuth client ID.
I set client, sheet info json files and information on my project.
But when my website connect to spreadsheet, error always happens.
This is error message.

```
Google_Service_Exception (404)
{ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "errors": [ { "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound" } ], "status": "NOT_FOUND" } }
```

This is my code that error happens.

```
        $sheet = Sheets::spreadsheet(config('sheets.post_spreadsheet_id'))->get(config('sheets.post_sheet_it'));
```

`Until Sheets::spreadsheet(config('sheets.post_spreadsheet_id'))` is executed, no error.

But `->get(...)` generates this error.